# How to input PHP into HTML placeholder?

Tags: php, html, cookies, setcookie

I'm trying to make it so a cookie saves the users name and then puts it in the HTML placeholder next time they visit. What's the most efficient way of doing this?

I searched the other threads and tried using 'include' and putting $name in the input placeholder, but it ends up giving me errors because txtName and txtAge are undefined. I'm unsure how to reorganize my code to get it working.

PHP&HTML Doc#1:

```
    $doc = "<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang='en'>
        SOME HTML........
        <input type='text' name='txtName' id='txtName' placeholder='$name'>
        SOME HTML........
    </html>";

echo $doc;
```

PHP/Doc#2:

```
<?php 

    $name = $_POST["txtName"];
    $age = $_POST["txtAge"];
    $k = $_POST['radRaceLength'];


    ///check if cookie exists
    if ( isset($_COOKIE["nameData"]) ){
        $name = $_COOKIE["nameData"];
    }
    else{
        $name = $name;
    }
    if ( isset($_COOKIE["ageData"]) ){
        $age = $_COOKIE["ageData"];
    }
    else{
        $age = $age;
    }
    setcookie("nameData", $name, time() + 3600, "/");
    setcookie("ageData", $age, time() + 3600, "/");

    $fiveK = 10 + ($age / 2); 
    $tenK = 18 + ($age / 3);
    $member = isset($_POST["chkMember"]) ? $fiveK = $fiveK - 5 AND $tenK = $tenK - 5: $member = NULL;

    if ( !$name AND $age <= 21 )
        echo "Please provide a name and valid age";
    else

        echo $name.', you are registered for the '.$k.' race. Your fee is: ';
        echo ( ($_POST["radRaceLength"] == "5K")? "$fiveK":"$tenK" );



?>
```

Comment: try this

'<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        SOME HTML........
        <input type="text" name="txtName" id="txtName" placeholder="'.$name'">
        SOME HTML........
    </html>';

Comment: use single quote $doc = '.....' ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DOC1: Check if cookie was set in doc2

```
<$php
$name = "Name";
if(isset($_COOKIE["nameData"])) {$name = $_COOKIE["nameData"];}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
SOME HTML

<input type='text' name='txtName' id='txtName' placeholder='<?php echo $name ?>' />

SOME HTML
</html>;
```

DOC2:

```
<?php 
$name = 'Name'; $age = 'Age'; $k = 0;

//if data in cookie, set.
if (isset($_COOKIE["nameData"])) $name = $_COOKIE["nameData"];
if (isset($_COOKIE["ageData"])) $age = $_COOKIE["ageData"];

//if data in post, set and rewrite cookie.
if(isset($_POST["txtName"])) $name = $_POST["txtName"];
if(isset($_POST["txtAge"])) $age = $_POST["txtAge"];
if(isset($_POST["radRaceLength"])) $k = $_POST["radRaceLength"];

setcookie("nameData", $name, time() + 3600, "/");
setcookie("ageData", $age, time() + 3600, "/");

$fiveK = 10 + ($age / 2); 
$tenK = 18 + ($age / 3);
$member = isset($_POST["chkMember"]) ? $fiveK = $fiveK - 5 AND $tenK = $tenK - 5: $member = NULL;

if (!$name AND $age <= 21 ) {
   echo "Please provide a name and valid age";
} else {
   echo "{$name}, you are registered for the {$k} race. Your fee is: ";
   echo ( ($_POST["radRaceLength"] == "5K")? "$fiveK":"$tenK" );
}
?>
```

Comment: It works! Thank you for going the extra mile and rewriting it beautifully! very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

## Some problems:

There is no need to add this section:

```
else{
    $name = $name;
}
```

at all. Also applicable to this section:

```
else{
    $age = $age;
}
```

If you want to do more than one line of PHP in a `If-Statement` like in

```
else

    echo $name.', you are registered for the '.$k.' race. Your fee is: ';
    echo ( ($_POST["radRaceLength"] == "5K")? "$fiveK":"$tenK" );
```

You should wrap it in braces like this:

```
else{

    echo $name.', you are registered for the '.$k.' race. Your fee is: ';
    echo ( ($_POST["radRaceLength"] == "5K")? "$fiveK":"$tenK" );

}
```

## Answering your question:

The most efficient way of reading a cookie and putting it in a HTML input?

I don't know why all people try to add this to the begging of their questions, as the term efficient, does not make sense in many situations. You are just reading a cookie and putting it in an HTML input.

So , the simple and more likely correct answer is, just do it.

## Further suggestion

Dont kill markup like that. Instead open PHP tags whenever you really need it, and close it whenever you dont!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <input type="text" name="txtName" placeholder="<?php echo $name;?>">
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful suggestions! I learned a few things from your post. I usually ask for 'efficient' answers because I learn more from them, rather than it being written plainly. Example; I learned how to use the ternary operator from someone's answer when he/she could have simply used IF statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate your variable... in your case just do this... 
change from **placeholder='$name'** to **placeholder='.$name.'**

```
 $doc = "<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang='en'>
        SOME HTML........
        <input type='text' name='txtName' id='txtName' placeholder='.$name.'>
        SOME HTML........
    </html>";

echo $doc;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this might work:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="<?php echo isset($_COOKIE['firstname']) ? $_COOKIE['firstname'] : 'Your First Name'; ?>" />
```